# iTerm.app vs Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, iterm2

So, I just downloaded iTerm2. I am using zsh in both the apps. iTerm seems to be faster than Terminal.

What things matter when you have a wrapper application around a shell?
I want to use iTerm but I don't know why it would be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iTerm2's list of features](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features) look pretty nice, but if you don't use any of them it won't make a difference for you. A faster term isn't anything to complain about either.

I think the most valuable thing for me would be the 256 colors for vim and perhaps a few other things that take advantage of having 256 colors.

Comment: note that you can change Terminal to xTerm 256 under Preferences > Settings > Advanced - Declare Terminal As > xterm-256 Color